# Is it possible to clone an Azure Container App?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-apps

I do not want to define the env variables for each container app so I would prefer to clone one with the variables already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest), there's no clone functionality.